# SQL Server - Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am getting the following error in a subquery

```
Select*
from
(select 

CONVERT (BIGINT,AX$AC1) as [Account]
from 
[x].[y]
where [AXOBJ] >399999 AND [AX$AC1] NOT like '%NON BENCHMARK%')a
where a.[Account]>=510980
```

It returns 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I ran following to capture the data type of this table

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='y'

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
|-------------|-----------|
| AXOBJ       | char      |
| AX$AC1      | char      |
```

The following code return 39 integer values

```
select 

CONVERT (BIGINT,AX$AC1) as [Account]
from 
[x].[y]
where [AXOBJ] >399999 AND [AX$AC1] NOT like '%NON BENCHMARK%' GROUP BY AX$AC1
```

I am not sure where it going wrong.

Comment: Without sample data we can but guess. Replace `CONVERT (BIGINT,AX$AC1) ` with `TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT,AX$AC1)`. I bet you get some `NULL` values. But why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` anyway? A value like `'1.0'` *cannot* be converted to a `bigint`.

Comment: AXOBJ & AX$AC1 are of type char, what is the length of that column ?

Comment: The simple answer is to know your datatypes, understand the rules for implicit conversion, and understand how to write / use literals of a specific datatype.

Comment: @Larnu many thanks. Yes, `TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT,AX$AC1)` returns bunch of null values. I modified my query as `where [AXOBJ] >399999 AND [AX$AC1] NOT like '%NON BENCHMARK% AND TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, AX$AC1)>=510980`. It is giving me what I need. But why are you storing numerical data as a varchar anyway? _  I am not the DBA. I am just accessing the view. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [try_convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
select [AX$AC1], [Account]
from [x].[y] cross apply
     ( values (try_convert(BIGINT, AX$AC1), try_convert(BIGINT, [AXOBJ])
              ) 
     ) a([Account])
where a.[AXOBJ] > 399999 AND 
      [y].[AX$AC1] NOT like '%NON BENCHMARK%' and
      a.[Account] > 510980;
```

You will find `null` values where conversation will fail by removing `[Account] > 510980`.

Comment: But AXOBJ is a string too. And I think you mean "where **conversion** will fail"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your where condition `where [AXOBJ] >399999`, also the last where condition `where a.[Account]>=510980`.

Try the below code

```
Select*
from
(select 

CONVERT (BIGINT,AX$AC1) as [Account]
from 
[x].[y]
where CONVERT(bigint,[AXOBJ]) >399999 AND [AX$AC1] NOT like '%NON BENCHMARK%')a
where CONVERT(bigint,a.[Account]) >= 510980
```